# PhoneGap contact picker

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, contacts

Now that PhoneGap is version 2.0, is there a (potentially undocumented) way to have a contact picker?

The docs make it seem like I'd have to write my own in JavaScript by requesting ALL the user's contacts, then building my own in-app contact picker.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts

I've found a one-off plug-in for Android, but that's not helpful if there's no plug-in for iPhone, cause then I'd still have to write my own.  I'm looking for a device agnostic method that says "let the user go pick a contact, then send them back here with that contact info"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you can use this solution for Android as well but for iPhone you can use the `.chooseContact()` method.

Example:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="contactChooser()">Choose a contact</a>


    function contactChooser(){

    //The chooseContact method will open a new window with all you contacts
    navigator.contacts.chooseContact(

        //After picking a name you will receive the id of the chosen contact
        function(id){

            //In an options variable you can set some filter parameters
            //In this example we will use the Id to receive the data of the chosen contact
            var options = {
                filter: ""+id
            }

            //In the fields variable we're going to set the fields we want to receive
            //'*' = every data. More field values are explained
            // here: http://bit.ly/T8YyuE
            var fields = ['*'];

            navigator.contacts.find(fields, onPickContactSuccess, onPickContactError, options);
        }, null);
    }

    function onPickContactSuccess(contacts){
        //contacts contains all data you've requested

        var _name = contacts[0].name

        alert('Last: '+_name.familyName+' First: '+_name.givenName);
    }
```

Comment: Just a note: This appears to be an undocumented feature for iOS only.  See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/JI42d5prb-I